# Setting JVM Local Network Interface

Tags: java, networking

How do I tell the JVM which network interface to bind? For the life of me I cannot find any reference to this in the documentation or Googling. I have machine with multiple interfaces and I want to use a specific interface that is not the default. Is there a commmandline parameter? Yes, I could do it in code setting it in java.net.Socket.bind(laddr) but that would mean seeking out and changing all such instances which is unnecessarily difficult. There must be a way to do it for the entire JVM. Or at the OS level?

UPDATE: So as people have stated, there is amazingly no way to do this at the JVM level. Unfortunately we use JNDI for LDAP and DNS and near as I can tell there's no way to override in JNDI either (presumably because JNDI is really just a wrapper around various implementations). That means either trying to override ServerSocketImpl at the JVM level (not clear that can be done either and it doesn't address TLS sockets either) or it must be done at the OS level (such as using a "docker"). IMO this is a BUG in Java.

Comment: Unless you have a strong host model OS e.g. Linux is not, even if you specify the interface, the OS is free to ignore your hint.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model

Comment: You could run in a container e.g. docker, which can only access one interface.

Comment: As your program starts you can use `Socket.setSocketImplFactory(SocketImplFactory)` to override the default behaviour of new Sockets and set the interface each time.

Comment: You seem interested in choosing a default IP address for your serversocket, not quite a network interface (MAC), right? My guess is, look at the OS and see if changing the metric (route cost) or perhaps some listing order in the depth of the OS can make the jvm choose it. But beware, most decent server programs have a cfg to spec the listening IP; that's expected and it kinda shows there is no solid mechanism for a default too. Sorry, but you should really change your code to pick up a system property for example. Still worth doing even with 100 locations to fix.